# Amsterdam: day tickets from Sloterdijk to Centraal?

Tags: trains, public-transport, amsterdam

I'm considering staying on Sloterdijk, Amsterdam for a few days, and I'm trying to find out if there is any day/multi-day ticket that allows me to take the train from Sloterdijk to Centraal, which according to Google Maps is the fastest route to the city center.

The [GVB day ticket/multi-day ticket](http://en.gvb.nl/ontdek-amsterdam/gvb-dag-meerdagenkaart) only mentions bus, tram and metro, so I'm almost sure it would not allow me to take these trains.

The [NL Amsterdam Travel Ticket](https://www.ns.nl/producten/en/uitleg-overige-producten/p/amsterdam-travel-ticket), slightly more expensive, mentions bus, tram, metro and ferry, and also *Including 2nd class return train ticket*, which I suppose works only once, and is intended for the Schiphol airport.

Finally, there's a [NL day ticket for all trains](https://www.ns.nl/producten/en/losse-kaartjes/p/dagkaart), but it's overkill at 51,40€ *per day*!

My conclusion so far is that each travel on the train will have to paid for individually (2,20€ on OV-chipkaart/3,20€ on single-use chipkaart). Did I miss other ticket options?

Note: I initially thought that Sloterdijk was *inside* Amsterdam, but apparently it's a separate village. This might explain the absence of such tickets...

Comment: Will you be coming to Amsterdam by car?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Sloterdijk was a village out of Amsterdam but has now been gulped up by the city and is part of it. Just like the villages around London are part of Greater London.

It is within the city bus system area and on those buses you can use the travel passes for the city. And depending on where you want to be in Amsterdam, the bus might well be faster than going by train and take a bus from the Central station.

The [OV9292 planner](http://9292.nl/en) will tell you door to door, your hotel to wherever you want to go, how to get there. You can even set it to 'no train' to get that out of the results.

When you arrive you can ask whether there still is a bus pass that allows travel on the NS trains (national railways) within the Amsterdam area. I will look further and update if I do find one.

An OV chip seems a good investment but you need to realize that at the start of any train travel you need to have €20 on it, even for just a €2.20 'within the city' run. And it has to be a different OV chip for each of you, so as a couple you can be left with about €35 on your cards. Officially you can get a refund for that money, but it takes time and effort and you will always lose some money.

The Amsterdam tourist information office site has a [list of public transport passes](http://www.iamsterdam.com/en/visiting/plan-your-trip/getting-around/public-transport) and non of them includes the train within Amsterdam, apart from the 'Schiphol return' which you already found.

An [other site](http://amsterdam.info/transport/) mentions renting a bicycle, which might suit you. It is cheaper than three bus or tram tickets per day, but it does include some effort. Riding is safe and helmets are not used by those using utility bikes as rentals mostly are.
Dutch cyclist do only use helmets when going high speed or off road, as a rule, that means that if you want to rent a bike and peddle on the bike lanes, you can do so without helmets, which makes bike rental much easier for tourists.
Helmets are not only not mandatory, they are also not often used.

Comment: Could you please clarify what you mean by "helmets are not used by those using utility bikes"? You mean they're not mandatory?

Comment: I answered the comment in an edit to the question.

Comment: NS trains within Amsterdam used to be within the municipal fare system (or, at least, it used to be possible to use the strippenkaart on NS routes within the city).  Did something change to exclude them?

Comment: With the end of the Strippenkaart, the local transport situation has changed. Now all train travel, also within the cities, is on the train payment system of the OV chip cards. The city 'bus' passes are only valid on the other public transport in the city, or just on those of one company.

Answer (score 3):

I don't know any other day ticket that would fit the bill but you can go from Sloterdijk station to many places in the city with the subway/metro or tramways and to Amsterdam Centraal with a bus. So the issue is one of commercial/administrative policy (trains are operated by another company), not merely the fact that Sloterdijk would be out of the GVB day ticket's validity area. It's certainly fully integrated with Amsterdam nowadays.